# javascript 'use strict' and and Object.defineProperty setter

Tags: javascript, class, es6-class

```
'use strict';

class DataClass{

        constructor(name){
            this.name = name;

            Object.defineProperties(this, {
                _archives :{
                    value : []

                },
                temperature : {

                    enumerable : true,
                    set : function(value){

                        // error message : InternalError: too much recursion
                        //this.temperature = value;
                        //error message  in case of 'use strict' : ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable temperature
                        temperature = value;
                        this._archives.push(value);

                    },
                    get : function(){
                        return ' yyy ';
                    } 
                },

            });
        }



 }



 var dataClass1 = new DataClass('giovanni');
 dataClass1.temperature = 45;
 console.log(dataClass1.temperature);
```

When i try to run this code in strict mode i get always this error **ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable temperature**
i would like to understand which is the best way to work around this problem

Comment: What are you trying to do with that line? Just omit it, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use 'use strict' you cannot use an undeclared variable.
After "this.name = name;" put "var temperature;"

```
'use strict';

class DataClass{

        constructor(name){
            this.name = name;
            var temperature; // <- private variable, completely different from the public one.
            Object.defineProperties(this, {
                _archives :{
                    value : []

                },
                temperature : { // <- public variable Object.temperature, internally this.temperature

                    enumerable : true,
                    set : function(value){

                        // error message : InternalError: too much recursion
                        //this.temperature = value; <-- Call the set again, that's why the loop.
                        //error message  in case of 'use strict' : ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable temperature
                        temperature = value;
                        this._archives.push(value);

                    },
                    get : function(){
                        return ' yyy ';
                    } 
                },

            });
        }



 }



 var dataClass1 = new DataClass('giovanni');
 dataClass1.temperature = 45;
 console.log(dataClass1.temperature);
```

Comment: thanks it works, but it looks weird as temperature in the constructor doesn t look like the same variable instantiate  in the Object.defineProperties, do you have any idea how this is working

Comment: They are not the same variable.
Object.defineProperties defines a variable of the object, it is accessed by this.temperature or Object.temperature if it is from outside.

var temperature defines a variable of the "environment" (not exactly what it is called), it is accessed simply by name and is a private variable, it cannot be accessed from outside.
Summary: one is Object.temperature and another is temperature.I do not know if I explained well.

Comment: So this means that Object.temperature it will be never valorized (itself), let say  that if I use Object.defineProperty with set and get, that defined property became a *_placeholder_*  pointing to internal properties. Is that correct?

Comment: It is correct but more than pointing to properties it points to a function (get, set).